# Layer.bindTooltip doesn't work in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geojson, tooltip

My objective is to plot polygons and assign a tooltip label to each one. For some reason, my code doesn't seems to work.

```
poly_geojson = L.geoJson(poly_gon,{
    onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        if (feature.properties.sourceLang == "en") {
            layer.bindTooltip("<h4>"+feature.properties.name+"</h4>")
        }
        else {
            layer.bindTooltip("<h4>"+feature.properties.name+"</h4>")
        }
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Specification of `onEachFeature` option is wrong, it should be: `onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) { … }`

Comment: hey, i still face the same issue, the code works if i replace 'bindTooltip' with 'bindPopup'. im not sure if i am doing this right

Comment: If you corrected syntax, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>According to leaflet's [documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.0.html#tooltip)  - after `bindTooltip()` - add `openTooltip()`</strike>    
Code - I added the 'options fix' from the comments:

`poly_geojson = L.geoJson(poly_gon,{
    onEachFeature : function(feature, layer) {
        if (feature.properties.sourceLang == "en") {
            layer.bindTooltip("<h4>"+feature.properties.name+"</h4>");
        }
        else {
            layer.bindTooltip("<h4>"+feature.properties.name+"</h4>");
        }
    }
}).addTo(map);`

EDIT: no need to use openTooltip() please check this [codepen](https://codepen.io/nettaben/pen/qBEGPyO)

Comment: Any special reason for opening all tooltips upon definition with `.openTooltip()`? This is not necessary unless you want to have all the tooltips open initially. Usually behavior for tooltip is to be opened upon mouse over.

Comment: If a codePen is avail - it'll be easier to explain. I might be wrong of course.  @TomazicM